# Making a variable term have its own CSS when it appears within another variable

Tags: php, css

Within the variable `$row["title"]` below, I would like the variable `$find` to have the following CSS:

```
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #004284;
            background-color: #FFFF00;
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

```
echo '<td class="sitename1search">'.$row["title"].'</td>';
```

Comment: Sorry, can you try to describe what you want another way? Variables can't have any associated CSS, only HTML elements can.

Comment: I think you're trying to emphasize (or by highlighting) the results when you search?

Comment: If @Manie's guess is correct, I'd refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757556/highlight-multiple-keywords-in-search

Comment: Thanks, deceze... I used the info you link to.

Answer (score 0):

First, declare the CSS this way:

```
td.sitename1search span.find {
    font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #004284;
    background-color: #FFFF00;   
}
```

Then, when you construct `$row["title"]`, wrap the `$find` variable in a span like this:

```
$row["title"] = " ... <span class='find'>$find</span> ... ";
```