# What is wrong with this regex?

Tags: php, regex

i need the following -

if i have a sentence

```
$str = "i like programming very much";
```

and i search for a word

```
$word = "r";
```

i expect it to return the sentence

"i like *p***r***og***r***aming*  *ve***r***y* much"

I wrote the following regex for it, but it sometimes doesn't work.

`$str = preg_replace("/([^\s{".preg_quote($word)."}]*?)(".preg_quote($word).")([^\s{".preg_quote($word)."}]*)/siu","<span class='pice1'>$1</span><span class='pice2'>$2</span><span class='pice1'>$3</span>",$str);`

Could you tell me what i wrote wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE:

for example it doesn't work when

```
$str = "ameriabank"; and $word = "ab";
```

...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to highlight words that contain a given sub-string?

Comment: That seems to be the gist of it, and it seems that people commonly want to solve that problem. I think it's been solved before. Search for "highlight" and I'm sure you'll get lots of good answers.

Comment: in example i've shown what i expect. I need to highlight the whole word if it contains the sub_word, but highlight the sub_word in other way, then other part of word. As in example(see the word programming)...

Comment: Location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757556/highlight-multiple-keywords-in-search

Comment: @shamittomar they do another thing. i need two types of highlighting in each word which contain keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont't you just use str_replace()? I think it's more simple

```
$search = "ab";
$word = "ameriabank";
$newstr = "<span class=\"pice1\">".str_replace($search, $word, "</span><span class=\"pice3\">".$search."</span></span class=\"pice1>\")."</span>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "i like programming very much";
$w = "r";
echo preg_replace("/($w)/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
```

Output:

```
i like p<b>r</b>og<b>r</b>amming ve<b>r</b>y much
```

Answer to the comment: do it in two steps.

```
$str = "i like programming very much ready tear";
$w = "r";
$str = preg_replace("/\\b((?:\\w+|\\b)$w(\\w+|\\b))\\b/", "<i>$1</i>", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/($w)/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
echo $str;
```

output:

```
i like <i>p<b>r</b>og<b>r</b>amming</i> <i>ve<b>r</b>y</i> much <i><b>r</b>eady</i> <i>tea<b>r</b></i>
```

Comment: what about other parts of word `programming`? i need to highlight them too, but in other way(not bold i mean)...

Answer (score 1):

visit [highlight multiple keywords in search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757556/highlight-multiple-keywords-in-search) and be amazed.

Answer (score 1):

What about this way :

```
$str = "i like programming very much";
$word = "r";
$list = explode(' ',$str);
for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++) {
    if(preg_match("/$word/", $list[$i])) {
        $list[$i] = '<i>'.preg_replace("/$word/siu", "<b>$word</b>", $list[$i]).'</i>';
    }
}
$str = implode(' ',$list);
echo $str,"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "i like programming very much";
$word = "r";
function highlight($matches)
{
    global $word;
    return '<span class="pice1">'.str_replace($word,'<span class="pice2">'.$word.'</span>',$matches[0]).'</span>';
}
echo $str = preg_replace_callback("/([^\s]*?".preg_quote($word, '/')."[^\s]*)/siu", highlight, $str);
```

do the job(and it works with foreign languages too)...