# Highlight multiple keywords in search (non-english characters)

Tags: php, preg-replace

Found this function to highlight keywords in a search string in the thread [highlight multiple keywords in search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757556/highlight-multiple-keywords-in-search)

```
function highlight($text, $words) {
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
    if(!$m)
        return $text;
    $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';
    return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}
```

But it does not work for non-english characters, how can I tweak it to work with e.g. å ä ö ô etc.

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem. I could solve it thanks to this question and own [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30260166/1883256).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are searching for **unicode** characters? \w Only matches [a-zA-Z0-9_].

For example this matches persian digits :

```
preg_match( "/[^\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}\x]+/u" , '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰' );
```

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Just create a character class with the characters you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

You better do it with JS after the page loads it with needed encoding:

```
function paint_keys( str_to_replace , words ){
temp_reg = str_to_replace;
if( /\s/g.test( temp_reg ) ) temp_reg = temp_reg.split( " " ); // Breaking our searching keywords into an array;
else return words.split( temp_reg ).join( "<span class='painted'>" + temp_reg + "</span>" );
for( z = 0 ; z < temp_reg.length ; z++ ){
    if( temp_reg[ z ] != "" ) words = words.split( temp_reg[ z ] ).join( "<span class='painted'>" + temp_reg[ z ] + "</span>" );
}
return words;
}
```

Of course, you can replace the `<span class='painted'>" + temp_reg + "</span>` to whatever you need.

If you need it to be done by php only - use the principle of breaking the keys to array by `explode( "\s" , $words );` - that will give you an array of symbols only and then loop to replace the string for each word in the array.