# regex to also match accented characters

Tags: php, regex, character, non-ascii-characters, accent-insensitive

I have the following PHP code:

```
$search = "foo bar que";
$search_string = str_replace(" ", "|", $search);

$text = "This is my foo text with qué and other accented characters.";
$text = preg_replace("/$search_string/i", "<b>$0</b>", $text);

echo $text;
```

Obviously, "que" does not match "qué". How can I change that? Is there a way to make `preg_replace` ignore all accents?

The characters that have to match (Spanish):

```
á,Á,é,É,í,Í,ó,Ó,ú,Ú,ñ,Ñ
```

I don't want to replace all accented characters before applying the regex, because the characters in the text should stay the same:

"This is my **foo** text with **qué** and other accented characters."

and not

"This is my **foo** text with **que** and other accented characters."

Comment: Actually it's working for me. see screen shot:- http://prntscr.com/75gj1w

Comment: @A-2-A Nope. `qué` is not highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search = str_replace(
   ['a','e','i','o','u','ñ'],
   ['[aá]','[eé]','[ií]','[oó]','[uú]','[nñ]'],
   $search)
```

This and the same for upper case will complain your request. A side note: `ñ`  replacemet sounds invalid to me, as 'niño' is totaly diferent from 'nino'

Comment: I use str_ireplace with your answer, that is exaclty what I needed!

Comment: The website is for "lazy" people so it is correct that "n" matches "ñ" ;)

Answer (score 3):

The solution I finally used:

```
$search_for_preg = str_ireplace(["e","a","o","i","u","n"],
                                ["[eé]","[aá]","[oó]","[ií]","[uú]","[nñ]"],
                                $search_string);

$text = preg_replace("/$search_for_preg/iu", "<b>$0</b>", $text)."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the captured text in the replacement string, you have to use character classes in your `$search` variable (anyway, you set it manually):

```
$search = "foo bar qu[eé]"
```

And so on.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have some array that maps, say, `e` to `eé` and replace all occurrences of `vowel` with `"[" . $dict[$vowel] ."]"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining an array like this:

```
$vowel_replacements = array(
    "e" => "eé",
    // Other letters mapped to their other versions
);
```

Then, before your `preg_match` call, do something like this:

```
foreach ($vowel_replacements as $vowel => $replacements) {
    str_replace($search_string, "$vowel", "[$replacements]");
}
```

If I'm remembering my PHP right, that should replace your vowels with a character class of their accented forms -- which will keep it in place. It also lets you change the search string far more easily; you don't have to remember to replaced the vowels with their character classes. All you have to remember is to use the non-accented form in your search string.

(If there's some special syntax I'm forgetting that does this without a `foreach`, please comment and let me know.)