# On the fly keyword highlighting

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP search script and I want to highlight the keywords that the user has searched with  tags. How can I do this?

My code is:

```
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
$keywords=explode(' ',$_GET['q']);
foreach($keywords as $query){
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$likes[]="keywords LIKE '%{$query}%'";
}

$searchResult=mysql_query("select * from questions where ".implode('or ',$likes)."limit 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)){
    $results="<div class='webresult'>{$row['result']}</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081372/highlight-keywords-in-a-paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$row['result']` does not contain html, you can do a string replace: replace all keywords in the result with `<span class="highlight">keyword</span>`

A simple example:

```
...
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {
  $res = $row['result'];
  foreach($keywords as $kw) {
    $res = str_replace($kw, '<span class="highlight">' . htmlspecialchars($kw) . '</span>', $res);
  }
  $results="<div class='webresult'>{$res}</div>";
}
...
```

Comment: @Cosmo Posmo See Blowski's answer, but your search results are not reliable anyway as the visitor can enter for example an html tag as a search term.

Comment: @Cosmo Posmo I have added the complete `while` loop for the mysql results.

Comment: @Cosmo Posmo Sorry about that, just use `str_ireplace()` instead of `str_replace()`

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, depending on whether the result can contain HTML or not.

1. If the result can't contain HTML - use preg_replace. See here: [highlight multiple keywords in search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757556/highlight-multiple-keywords-in-search/2757619#2757619)
2. If it can contain HTML, then you will need to use a DOM parser to separate text from HTML. Example parsers include [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).